# Extract touching polygons using st_touches

Tags: r, vector, sf

I am trying to extract touching polygons using R. The polygons are some wall facades and gaps. When I use st_touches(), it gave all (empty) value. However, they do touch each other.

The issue is quite specific and you can download the data here [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UvGRhB8T_sb640aNLfyw6-YdR5yzA9uq/view?usp=sharing)

The code below is the one I am playing with

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(sf)

wall <- st_read("ep_wall.shp") %>%
  rename(Site = Site_ID) %>% 
  mutate(ID = row_number())
wallgap <- st_read("ep_wallgap.shp") %>%
  rename(Site = Site_ID)
wallfilled <- st_read("ep_wallfilled.shp") %>%
  rename(Site = Site_ID)

tmp <- wall
# buffer
tmp$buffer <- st_buffer(wall, dist = 0.01)
# select only blocks which are not at the edge (using previous buffer)
tmp$covered <- st_covered_by(tmp$buffer, wallfilled) %>% lengths > 0
tmp <- subset(tmp, tmp$covered[{TRUE}])
# Add column Gap
tmp["Gap"] <- NA

st_touches(tmp, wallgap)
```

Results always look like this, which is not satisiying..

```
Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 462, where the
predicate was `touches'
first 10 elements:
 1: (empty)
 2: (empty)
 3: (empty)
 4: (empty)
 5: (empty)
 6: (empty)
 7: (empty)
 8: (empty)
 9: (empty)
 10: (empty)
```

I also tried to change the precision but the results still not good.

We can see from the map view that they do touch each other. So really curious about how it went empty when I used st_touches.

[image: Red ones are wall bricks and blue ones are gaps, they do touch each other]

Any ideas on why it happens?

Comment: You need to review the meaning of the "touch" relationship. Polygon objects which have areal intersection overlap do not touch (they intersect).

Comment: the "touching" predicate is tricky, and can fail due to issues with imprecise data capture and floating point math - I have found `sf::st_is_within_distance()` more reliable, when used with a reasonable distance argument (that may need tuning for a given context)

Comment: Also if the boundaries that are meant to be shared are not made of exactly same vertices it is almost inevitable that there a small unintentional overlaps. Successful use of "Touches" requires perfect topology.

Comment: Would someone like to explain all this in an Answer instead of comments or shall I do it?